# How do I use Type Hinting to show a List<Foo>

Tags: python-3.x

I have a bunch of classes which carry out functionality, but with type hinting I wanted to now have it show an instance of that class, Or a list of instances of that class.

```
class Foo:
  pass
class Bar:
  pass
class Win:
  pass
```

I then started seeing Typings, and was doing things like:

```
get_all_foos() -> list:
  return []
```

which makes sense, but i wanted it to be more verbose. Something akin to:

```
get_all_foos() -> list<Foo>:
  return []
```

I was looking online and it seems that I might need to use the LIST typing, instead of base *list*.

```
from typing import List
get_all_foo() -> List[Foo]:
  pass
```

While I dont think i was getting any errors, I wanted to make sure this was the correct way to do things per Python standard or if it suitable to just do:

```
get_all_foo() -> list[Foo]:
  pass
```

Comment: See [the official documentation](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kinds_of_types.html) of mypy.

Comment: When looking at it, there was no explicit documentation for Iterables, though when ctrl+f, I did get a reference to: `List[str]` which makes me think that `List[Foo]` is acceptable, though the return type ISNT a *List*, but instead a *list* as a Typing cant be instantiated.  So a List is not a Datastructure, but purely a Typing.

Comment: Well there is an example for `Tuples`, the same concept is applied for `Lists`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer, based on research on the python docs, is as follows.

A list is something which can be implemented.  It is a datastructure.

A List is a typing, which is used for type hinting.  It is not a datastructure.

For people familiar with other typed languages, my mistake was that I was mistaking a List also as an alternate Datastructure with a similar implementation of list.

So that means, that you can have a function:

```
get_all() -> List[Foo]: pass
```

BUT the return type can't be a List, for reasons stated above.

It would still be a list as that is the actual datastructure.  it is purely for decorator purposes.  I was having issues conceptually with the fact that I was trying to enforce typing by making things be a List as the samples were showing, but since it wasnt instantiable, it all made sense.

Therefore you would easily have

```
def get_all() -> List[Foo]: return []
```

which returns a list.  I was thinking both the hint and return should be the same type.